# How to have url rewrite to a specific port on Mac OS X server behind DD-WRT router?

Tags: apache-http-server, dd-wrt, url, dynamic-dns, rewrite

I've just setup a home web server using Mac OS X Lion's built-in Apache server.
I setup access my Subsonic music server running on port 4040 and my torrent remote control on port 9091, as well as the built in web server on port 80.  Fortunately, port 80 is unblocked so I've been able to access all of these using my DynDNS running on a DDWRT router.
I have my domain "example1.dyndns.org" hooked up with DD-WRT custom firmware and am able to access these individual services by "typing example1.dyndns.org:4040" or 9091.

I want to be able to access all these services at different /urls. So Subsonic would be example1.dyndns.org/subsonic.

From what I've researched, I suspect this could be done by either a Pro version of DynDNS, setting up a Virtual host in apache on either my DD-WRT router, or apache on my Lion Server, but I really need some direction on any of those.  I'm not a web designer, but can learn as long as I'm confident I'm headed in the right direction.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!
The secret was editing the Mac's built-in Apache virtual hosts!  I left my router to continue redirecting port 80 traffic to the server.
Credit to AngryInca over at Transmission's Forum for his [helpful instructions](https://forum.transmissionbt.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=8393#p43056).

So after launching Textedit in admin mode, I ended up adding this to my httpd.conf in order to enable Transmission (9091) to be accessed by going to www.examplewebsite.com/transmission and subsonic (4141) by going to ./music:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
RewriteEngine On
### BELOW FOR TRANSMISSION WEB INTERFACE ###

# Redirect requests to /transmission/ to /transmission/web/
RewriteRule /transmission[/]?$ /transmission/web/ [R=permanent]

# Forward all requests for /transmission to transmission-daemon
ProxyPass /transmission http://127.0.0.1:9091/transmission
ProxyPassReverse /transmission http://127.0.0.1:9091/transmission
redirect 301 /transmission/transmission/web/ /transmission/web/
redirect 301 /transmission/ /transmission/web/
redirect 301 /transmission /transmission/
### END TRANSMISSION WEB INTERFACE ###

### BELOW FOR Adam's Subsonic WEB INTERFACE ###
# Forward all requests for /music to subsonic-daemon
ProxyPass /music http://127.0.0.1:4141/music
ProxyPassReverse /music http://127.0.0.1:4141/music

### END SUBSONIC INTERFACE ###
</VirtualHost>
```

I added the redirects because sometimes transmission will mess up and try to go to the wrong url and the ProxyPass is so I could access my server at the website url on my local network (I did have to change a setting on my router to allow this though).